# How to configure MSILoggingLocation in InstallScript Project?

Tags: installshield

Creating package using Installshield 2012 Spring. To detect the erros enabling MSILogs by creating the reg key using 'voicewarmupx'. All log files are creating in Temp folder. My requirement is to change the logging location from Temp folder some other directory. Is there any way to achieve this, kindly suggest it will be a great help

Comment: If that registry key works, that means this is MSI based, not a pure InstallScript project. But if you're calling it InstallScript, perhaps it's an InstallScript MSI project?

Comment: Yess, its InstallScript MSI project

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to control the location of logs generated by the Windows Installer Logging key. All you can do is override the location manually, such as by providing an explicit location at the MSI command line. In some cases you can do this by specifying arguments in the Setup.exe tab of the Releases view. But beware: this makes it hard or impossible to avoid generating the log.